# Передать EventObject через Socket

Tags: java, сокет, события

Нужно передать ивэнт через java-сокет. Пока мысль такая - в конструктор ивента передавать сокет,и пусть он отправляет ключевое слово для разбора, и всю ин-цию внутри ивента, а с другой стороны создает новый объект ивента. Вопрос - а он перехватится в таком случаи, или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать сокет в ивент - это epic fail. И нет, он не перехватится. Созданный ивент надо слать в очередь руками. Если так уж хочется как-нибудь нахаляву, так отправьте его через сериализацию благо он Serializalble.

Comment: тогда через SocketChannel?

Comment: Это не важно через что.

Comment: сразу вспомнились примеры из книги :)
    Account a = new Account();
    a.create(connection);

а по теме: я бы сделал обвертку для сокета что-то на подобии
EventSender в котором на основе EventObject создавал экземпляр другого сериализируемого класса(попытка избавится от ошибок, уверен что на 2м компе вашего обьекта по getSource не будет, возможно даже что класса унаследованого от EventObject тоже). который успешно передавал бы по сети.

Comment: Пример в книге, вероятно, был упрощён для того, чтобы продемонстрирвать что-то другое. На деле такая конструкция нежизнеспособна.   "EventObject создавал экземпляр другого сериализируемого класса" - а зачем это нужно? Он сам по себе сериализуемый класс. А если на том конце его нет, то тогда о чём вообще речь может идти? Он ведь в любом случае не будет принят.